# How to protect RESTful API

Tags: rest, authentication, playframework, authorization

I have been looking for a way to protect my RESTful APIs. This appeared simple, but it seems to not be so simple. First off, I am writing an iOS app connecting to a Play Framework server. None of this has anything to do with Google, Facebook, Twitter, or LinkedIn (shocking I know). Oh, and my current plans do not require custom apps to use my APIs, its just my apps for the time being.

**Basic Authentication**

What appeared to be simple was a basic user/pass on a /auth method managing a cookie session. That may draw some groans as being too simple or weak but mostly it moved identity to a session key quickly verified. My initial setup was to expire the sessions every day, but that lead to the iOS app forcing a login daily proving to be an annoyance.

**OAuth**

I posted a question on an iOS board and received a blunt direction towards OAuth. My research of OAuth began but holy sh*t is that complicated and there does not seem to be any server side examples... just plenty of people complaining about how frustrating it is. All the client examples show connecting to Google, Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn. Oh Joy!

After watching Eran Hammer's rant about OAuth1 and OAuth2, it seemed fruitless to continue and his OZ idea (which looks really clean) is only at the early stages in node.js.

**Question**

So, my question to the broad StackOverflow community is... what do you do for securing your REST APIs?

Comment: Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784499/server-and-ssl-api-security

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest to consider approach used by biggest players i.e. Amazon Web Services or Windows Azure - [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). Although it isn't comfortable in implementation, as you can see it's trusted technique.

The general idea is to sign the request's parts (i.e. headers) in the iOS with secret key and try to recalculate it on the Play app to verify that request is authentic and not manipulated. If it won't fail, you can be (almost) sure, that was sent from somebody, who uses valid secret key.

Take a look into [Windows' document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx)  to get the concept (I think that for common task, you can use the less number of elements used for signing).

There is also other [interesting post](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) (based on AWS authentication) which describes whole process even better.

**Edit**

Of course you should realize that authentication in iOS and securing API requests are  different things, even if you'll expire your session every 15 minutes, you can't be sure that *somebody* won't *overhear* it and then will be able to send a fake request from the outside. Signing every request should minimize the risk.

On the other hand, if you'll prepare *clear rules* for signing the requests and will write short doc (which I recommend even for yourself), you can deliver it to the other developer and he'll be able to implement it in (almost) any platform supporting SHA256, so you will have API ready for using from 3-rd party apps - if you'll decide to publish it in the future.

Comment: Thank you for directing to HMAC. I had read the AWS post you mentioned prior to posting here. It ends up similar to OAuth 2-legged, but its easier to understand for some reason. But... I just cannot help wondering how this is different from SSL which hides all the complexity from me. Would I be better off just doing a user/pass session over SSL? What is the downside to that and is that what others end up doing to avoid the complexities OAuth and HMAC bring?

Comment: That's matter of taste, using SSL you need to add front-end HTTP server on top of the Play app(s) as there's no native SSL support in Play 2.x, also you need to buy a SSL certificate and renew it every year. HMAC signing approach is more 'independent' and I would choose especially for temporary apps with relatively small APIs. I need actually add one more thing, described HMAC offers signing messages, but doesn't encrypt its body so it's dedicated for authentication, but can't ensure the full privacy, be carefull if you're gonna send sensitive data.

Comment: I'm new to this topic, and though I read the links, I still need clarification (perhaps others do to). It seems to me that with HMAC you can authenticate the client app with the server, but you don't get any user-based authorization. Am I wrong?

Related: I thought that I understood OAuth provides both authentication and authorization capability. Am I wrong about that too?

Answer (score 0):

Since Play Framework is in Java, you could use [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)

I haven't used it yet.. (I am planning to though) So I don't know if it's the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something simple, send the authorization code / password in a custom header over HTTPS .

Comment: That is what I have been wondering as well. What is the downside to doing that?

Answer (score 0):

So the only problem with the Basic Authentication approach was that the user has to login every day? Why not offer the user an option to save his username/password on the device? That way he can choose between security and convenience.

Comment: That is what I have been doing so far, storing the user/pass in the Keychain for replaying it in the background.