# scala play framework post file

Tags: scala, file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0

In what way can I simulate file upload in play framework?
In other words I can upload file to server with such curl command:
curl -k -v -H "X-Agile-Authorization: token" -F uploadFile=c:\1.txt -F directory=/testpost -F basename=1.txt https:// api /post/file

how can I do the same without curl or browser in play framework. The aim is to upload file from one server to another.

Answer (score 4):

[Post on google-groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/MPtQlX-cWMQ/rdabLhGwytcJ):

> With org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity, you can manipulate multipart data easily. And then just write it to byte array buffer as you did.
>
> Ex: Upload photo to my facebook wall:

```
val entity = new MultipartEntity()
comment.map(msg => entity.addPart("message", new StringBody(msg, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))))
entity.addPart("source", new FileBody(photoFile))
val photoPostUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token="+facebookAccessToken
val outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
entity.writeTo(outputstream)
val header = (entity.getContentType.getName, entity.getContentType.getValue)
WS.url(photoPostUrl).withHeaders(header).post(outputstream.toByteArray()).await(5000).get.json
```

Dependency: `"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.3.1"` and `"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpmime" % "4.3.1"`.

If performance were a concern, you could do the same with WS's underlying client `WS.client`.

Comment: what is comment object here which package?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it's not possible to post a multipart/form-data through the WS API.

You can easily send a File `WS.url(myUrl).post(myFile)`, but not a form...
A workaround should be to use another library, like **Apache Http Client**.

Check this topic on the Play mailing-list: [[2.0] multipart/form-data in WS POST](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/MPtQlX-cWMQ/y_EVZpbUhRMJ)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the [Windows Azure Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx) or [Amazon S3](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) REST APIs, then using similar approach you can send files with [Play's WebServices API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaWS).

You just need to construct POST or PUT request and send it. Probably you'll need to care about authentication and/or authorization between both apps yourself (both APIs Windows and Amazon uses [HMAC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14095520/1066240) for this task)

Comment: As noted in Julien's answer above, WS does not support [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) `POST`ing. `multipart/form-data` is implied by `curl -F` option in the question. Though if you are free to send the file contents as the request body you can just do `WS.url(...).post(fileContentsAsByteArray)`. Also fit in a `.withHeaders(("Content-Type",...))` before sending, so the server knows how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The following example allows you to post `multipart/form-data`. It is a simple version that only works with `String` values, but it could easily be modified to use other types of data.

```
type NameValuePair = (String, String)
case class MultipartFormData(elements: Seq[NameValuePair], boundary: String)(
  implicit codec: Codec) {

  private val HTTP_SEPARATOR = "\r\n"
  private val actualBoundary = "--" + boundary
  private val endBoundary = actualBoundary + "--" + HTTP_SEPARATOR

  private val contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary
  private val content = elements.map(toPart).mkString + endBoundary

  val body = Body(content)

  case class Body(content: String)

  object Body {
    implicit val contentTypeOf:ContentTypeOf[Body] =
      ContentTypeOf(Some(contentType))
    implicit val writes: Writeable[Body] =
      Writeable(body => codec.encode(body.content))
  }

  private def toPart(nameValuePair: NameValuePair) = {
    val (name, value) = nameValuePair
    actualBoundary + HTTP_SEPARATOR +
      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"" + HTTP_SEPARATOR +
      HTTP_SEPARATOR +
      value + HTTP_SEPARATOR
  }
}
```

Usage is like this:

```
val data = MultipartFormData(formFields, "asdfghjkl123")

WS.url(myUrl).post(data.body)
```