# Build a REST API available to authorized apps only (like Facebook) with Laravel

Tags: rest, security, laravel

I'm building a REST API with Laravel and now I have an URL like

```
api.example.com/posts/3/comments
```

Now I'm wondering how to secure this API because as it's done now, anyone trying to make a `GET`, `POST`, ... request on this URL will get positive results.

I want this API to be available to authorized apps only (like Facebook API). For now, those apps are just my website and my iOS app.

I'm thinking about creating a table `applications` to store application's keys. But I don't know how to authenticate an app without publishing it key (which is obviously insecure).

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: When I Google `protect a rest api` I get a lot of results, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094529/how-to-protect-restful-api?

Comment: I also googled it and found tutorials but they're all about to authenticating users not apps.

Comment: For Laravel you could implement specific middlewares and implement them at route or controller level. I don't know how your authentication of an app differs from a user, though, but the logic involved shouldn't be all too different - something like an [api-guard](https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard) could be a solution (You could make your own implementation, of course.)

Comment: Restrict domains in your CORS headers

Comment: @Ciccio The difference between User authentication and App authentication is that the user can store his password in his mind whereas the web app can't (Javascript code is readable by anyone).

Comment: Wait... Yeeep. I think, I'm going to combine this with domain restriction and limit requests to ajax only.

Comment: That was not my point, hence I referenced the API guard package. Domain restriction and limiting to ajax requests alone will not be your solution; CORS is not security and the origin header can be spoofed.

Comment: Yep, but the problem with api-guard is that the app have to send the key for every request.. For webapps this key can be spied.

Comment: I'm also wondering, for Facebook case, if I set my app App Domain to `awesomeapp.com`, if I create a virtual host `awesomeapp.com` on my local machine, will Facebook detect it?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use something like [JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt). Using it, you create and store a token locally on the device, then every time someone makes a call to the server, you check the token and make sure that they are who they claim to be. You can store tokens for expiration if you like. They're typically used in stateless apps, so you will need to move away from the concept of a server session. You can use [Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) to filter HTTP requests entering your application.